# Save a new Datagrid Row to database

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, datagrid, ilist

Working in `C#` `WPF`.  Ok so I have a `datagrid` which is bound to an `entity framework` in my project.  The datagrid functions awesome when updating values which are displayed. I push the changes to the `database` using  `MyDataEntity.SaveChanges()` and everything works perfectly.

The issue comes up when adding a new row. I've set `CanUserAddRows="True"` in my XAML, so the user is able to add new rows.  The problem comes when i have to save the new rows to the database.  For some reason, the `SaveChanges()` call doesn't update the database. What I tried to do was pull all the values of the current row into an `IList` and then access the individual values so I could call `MyDataEntities.Add()' on the`RowEditEnding` event, but that made some other problems.  Mainly, I cant access the individual values in the IList.  when I look at the data in the list, it is in there, i have seen it, i just cant assign it to anything.

So really, my problem is two-fold.

1: How can I save the newly entered row to my database

2: How can I access the values in the IList

2 would be a better solution, because this way i could use the following code to fill additional columns in the database as well as pass data to other methods to get values for specific columns in the database.

```
private void DataGrid_RowEditEnding(object sender, DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
    IList rows = DataGrid.SelectedItems;
    TableName tbl = new TableName
    {
        Name = rows[1].ToString(),
        Qty = decimal.Parse(rows[4].ToString()),
        Type = rows[6].ToString(),
        TQty = ConvertQtoT(rows[4].ToString(), rows[6].ToString(),
        OnLIst = true
    };

        MyDataEntity.TableNames.Add(tbl);
        MyDataEntity.TableNames.SaveChanges(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Data grid doesn't come with insert functionality built in you have to implement your own insert function to insert into your collection

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can save a newly entered row into database from datagrid as follows:

First assign datasource to datagrid:

```
datagrid.ItemsSource = myview.GetList();
```

Next select the SelectionChanged Event of Datagrid:

```
private void datagrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
  objToAdd = datagrid.SelectedItem as clsName; //Entity Object
}
```

Next select CellEditEnding Event of Datagrid:

```
private void datagrid_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            FrameworkElement element1 = datagrid.Columns[0].GetCellContent(e.Row);
            if (element1.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
            {
                var colomn1 = ((TextBox)element1).Text;
                objToAdd.Column1 = Convert.ToInt32(Column1);
            }
            FrameworkElement element2 = datagrid.Columns[1].GetCellContent(e.Row);
            if (element2.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
            {
                var colomn2 = ((TextBox)element2).Text;
                objToAdd.Column2 = Convert.ToInt32(Column2);
            }
            FrameworkElement element3 = datagrid.Columns[2].GetCellContent(e.Row);
            if (element3.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
            {
                var colomn3 = ((TextBox)element3).Text;
                objToAdd.Column3 = Convert.ToInt32(Column3);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); 
        }
    }
```

Next select RowEditEnding Event of Datagrid:

```
private void datagrid_RowEditEnding(object sender, DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var Res = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to Create this new entry", "Confirm", MessageBoxButton.YesNo);
            if (Res == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
            {
                EntityObject.InsertEmployee(objToAdd);
                EntityObject.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); 
        }
    }
```

Hope this will help you...

Comment: This would work kind of... I still need to get some of the cell values and pass them to other methods.  Is there anyway I could parse the values of the IList and pass them that way?

Comment: In the above code you can get the values itself right. Still what you need. Elaborate it please...

Comment: I need to be able to get the individual values of each of the cells in the row.  I cant just push it straight into the database, because there are others columns which arent displayed that are populated based on the values entered.  So if there is a value in column 1, I need to get that value, then pass it to another method to do a conversion to get the value to insert in column 5.  So what I really need is a way to access the individual values in the row.  thanks

Comment: Ok I got it to work by using: `FrameworkElement element1 = datagrid.Columns[0].GetCellContent(e.Row);` and then `var colomn1 = ((TextBox)element1).Text;`.  Thanks for the help!!!!!